# How to fix Facebook (Build 14...), download manager process on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: facebook, download-manager

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 Model Number (SGH-I727R), running Android 4.1.2.

The problem that I am encountering is that there is this Facebook (Build 14....) thing that is running in my drop down menu. Unfortunately, that is all I can read on it because the rest of the brackets are cut off. It looks like it is trying to download something. When I hold my finger over it to get info, it says Download Manager version 4.1.2, followed by a long model number.

I am not sure how to end this process or get it to finish whatever it is trying to do. I've tried restarting my phone, uninstalling Facebook and then re-installing it. The problem still persists.  Please help me. It's just really annoying to constantly see that downloading icon running all of the time, and nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Go to downloads, click on it and send it to trash. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I hope this is your problem,rt?

just go in **downloads**,select **other downloads** and it will appear `facebook build 141046` and then **select that** and **click cancel**.

**OR**

**settings**-->**apps**-->**all**-->**download manager**-->**force stop**,
**disable** and **clear cache** then **enable** again

[Help/More](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-droid-dna/260794-facebook-build-141046-notification-bar-2.html)